# TYPO3 10 thumbnail generation sometimes not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I have a backend view that generates image thumbnails like this:

> <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="{fileReference.alternative}"
> title="{fileReference.title}" treatIdAsReference="1" width="100c"
> height="66c" />

This works! However, sometimes a thumbnail wont be generated (say theres eight images in an element, but the fifth and seventh don't work) and the page is left with a big image that breaks the layout but also is heavy on performance (this can be 5 MB images with a resolution of 5000x3000).
There is no pattern as far as I can tell and other views show a different sized thumbnail of the image just fine.

So I will assume that this just happens sometimes, maybe a server timeout caused it?

What I would like to know if theres a way to regenerate missing thumbnails somehow. I do not want to regenerate multiple thousand images in hopes to fix a couple of them.

edit:
A little update - I did a test. I downloaded the original image and reuploaded it (overwrite). Afterwards, the thumbnail was successfully generated

Comment: I would recommend thinking about whether 5000px makes sense as a starting size. I'm pretty sure, it's a timeout in the background tasks.
Maybe, EXT:image_resize can help you: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/image_autoresize

Comment: @JulianHofmann Reducing the initial resolution/filesize would reduce the chance of the issue happening, but it can still happen (I have thumbnails from 5MB images yet I am missing a thumbnail from a 3MB image) Let's say fifty 2MB image thumbnails have to be rendered on a page, that would likely also run into a timeout.
What I would rather understand is: Why is TYPO3 not trying to render a new thumbnail for those images. I assume there is some database entry that prevents it from doing so? I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Normally 2MB files should not run in timeout if images are not used extensively. How many files are you rending on each/this page? Maybe the hosting lacks performance? Have you checked/adjusted the PHP configuration (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/SystemRequirements/Index.html#id3)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so turns out that inside sys_file_processedfile, next to the correct entry, there were also faulty entries (same sha1 and checksum), but the faulty one had no identifier and TYPO3 picked that one...

I then deleted all processed files via "Maintenance" -> "Scan temporary assets" which also cleared the sys_file_processedfile table. Afterwards everything generated correctly. I still feel like there could be a middle way that does not require to remove all processed files and database entries and instead looks for faulty database entries only... but it works. Just takes a while to reprocess images afterwards.

Comment: Maybe, it could optimize your workaround by adding a scheduler task that periodically deletes those unwanted/faulty entries.

Comment: @JulianHofmann Yes, I'd like to have a scheduler that checks for faulty processed files. Though I am unsure if I know what a faulty database entry looks like. After clearing temporary assets, I already have dozens of new database entries in sys_file_processedfile without identifier or name and I don't know what their purpose is.

My idea for a scheduler would be (again, I don't know if that is correct):
Go through sys_file_processedfile > find entries with the same checksum > compare them: delete the older ones/the ones without an identifier